# want to add a subgrid in struts2 jquery grid

Tags: jquery, struts2

I have two grids department and student. Now I want to show department
grid always and whenever any row of that department grid is selected
student grid will open at the bottom of the department grid with all
the student data of that department. Can you help me on this. I am
using struts2 and jQuery.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

have you seen the [Grid Showcase](http://www.weinfreund.de/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase/index.action) from [Struts2 jQuery Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/)?

Maybe this is a good start to build your subgrid.

Comment: Check out working examples at:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154782/how-to-use-struts2-jquery-plugin-showcase-to-create-a-new-project/4642144#4642144