# How to use struts2 jquery plugin showcase to create a new project

Tags: jquery, eclipse, hibernate, struts2

I want to create a project using struts and hibernate. Also, I also wanted to use jQuery in it. I tried going through some tutorials in using spring+struts+hibernate+jquery but it just won't work.

I took a look at the struts2 jquery plugin showcase at http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/ and saw that it was what I really needed. Since the site already provided the codes for it, does anyone know how to use those codes? I tried creating a new project in Eclipse and copying all the source codes from the showcase plugin to my project but it's not working.

Can someone pls help me on this? I badly need to work this out since my project is due soon. :(

Hope someone could help asap.

Thanks everyone,

Honey =)

Comment: why does it not work? Are there any error messages? do you have a well configures web.xml and struts.xml?

Answer (score 1):

Just download https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/downloads/detail?name=struts2-jquery-showcase-2.4.1.war and start it in Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

Here are few working JQGrid Examples in Netbeans 6.9.

[Simple Struts2 Jquery grid](http://www.ziddu.com/download/13289687/SimpleJQGrid.rar.html)

[Struts2JQGrid with navigation](http://www.ziddu.com/download/13289688/JQGridWithNavigation.rar.html)

[Editable Struts2JQGrid](http://www.ziddu.com/download/13289689/JQEditableGrid.rar.html)

[Editable Sortable Searchable Struts2JqueryGrid](http://www.ziddu.com/download/13289690/JQGridEditableSearchSort.rar.html)

Simply resolve the references and get going.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are asking for aside from saying that you want to create a new Struts2 project that uses jQuery (among other technologies). If you would revise your question to indicate what specific problems you are having, then perhaps we can assist you.

I *do* want to point out that you don't need to use the jQuery plugin in order to use jQuery in Struts2. You can just include the necessary CSS and JavaScript and you are good to go. That's not to say that the jQuery plugin isn't good or that you shouldn't use it, just that you don't have to.